# Switching out connection strings in Sitecore 10

Tags: configuration

I'm in the process of upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10x.
With Sitecore 8.2 I was easily able to switch between databases simply by swapping out the connectionstrings, preferably by web.config transformation during deploys.

How would I switch databases in Sitecore 10x?  A simple swap does not work and gives me an error message which states

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

To me that means that there are other config files that need to be updated when I build or deploy other than just the `connectionstrings.config`. I have Googled and manually (windiff) searched for config and even xml files that might need to be updated but I have not discovered what else I need to do.

**Question**

Does anyone know what all config files I need to update when switching between databases and database locations for development and production environments? Using the exact same names in development and in production will not be an option because of my company's business rules.

Comment: ConnectionString config is the only place where the connections to the databases are defined (CMS/CD, Standalone roles). Config transform should work as normally. It could be one of your Sitecore 10 databases is corrupted, not upgraded ok. I recommend you try the 'swap' with an empty Sitecore 10 database.

Comment: Do I read you correctly in that you're attempting to point a Sitecore 10.x connection onto an 8.x database?   If so there is no trick to it, it flat out will never work. Sitecore has fundamentally changed its database structure between 8.x and 10.x

Comment: Mark, no, I'm not trying to connect a Sitecore 8.2 to a 10.x
Sorry for the confusion.

I'm trying to connect a Sitecore 10.1 (SC10dev) to a Sitecore 10.1 (SC10Prod)

Comment: Alina, that is a possibility. I will see if I can find any discrepancies between the databases.